# less command stop to work after set terminal title from .tcshrc

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm, less, tcsh

After I add following command to my `~/.tcshrc`:

```
echo "\033]0;${PROJECT_NAME}\007"
```

The `less` command in a new opened `gnome-terminal` stops working properly.
But `more` command is not affected.

This is what I see when trying to run `less` command:

```
less log

ESC]0;MYPROJ^G
log (END)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `less` is probably configured to pipe  its output through `lesspipe` or a similar script. This happens if environment variable `LESSOPEN` and/or `LESSCLOSE` is set, or an equivalent setting is used in the `~/.lesskey` file. The output from your `~/.tcshrc` is mixing in with the piped data and causing confusion.

Your `~/.tcshrc` apparently runs the command you added also when executed for a shell that does not have a TTY. This causes the problem you're seeing, and may also cause problems with `scp`, `rsync` or many other commands. *If you want to add a command that produces screen output to your `.tcshrc` or similar shell startup script, you should always make the command conditional so that it runs only on sessions that are interactive and/or have a TTY.*

The easiest way to fix it is to restrict any output in your `~/.tcshrc` to *interactive* shell sessions only. i.e. ones that will display a shell prompt. You can do it by making the output conditional, i.e. replacing the single line you added to `.tcshrc` with:

```
if ($?prompt) then
    echo "\033]0;${PROJECT_NAME}\007"
fi
```

Add this before setting any custom prompt.

Another way would be to silently test the validity of the TTY first:

```
tty -s && echo "\033]0;${PROJECT_NAME}\007"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! less works perfect after implementation.